Which constraint is checked first - primary key or unique key (on different columns)?
I have a program that synchronizes records in two databases. It relies on primary key violation on insert to know that record already exists, and then it makes applies an update to that record. That way, I avoid executing explicit SQL query for checking for the existence of a given record.
But for one particular table, I have primary key and unique index (for different columns than primary key). When I try insert a duplicate record in it, unique index violation occurs first, so the primary key violation does not happen, so the program algorithm fails.
Is there a way I can ensure that the primary key violation always occurs first? Or is there a explicit rule which check is made first?
Below is the DDL of the table:
CREATE TABLE BONS 
(
    BON_ID                 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BON_OPENTIME           TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    BON_CLOSETIME          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    BON_SALESMANID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BON_POSID              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BON_TABLENO            SMALLINT,
    BON_NUM                INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ...
);

/******************************************************************************/
/****                             Primary key                             ****/
/******************************************************************************/

ALTER TABLE BONS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BON_ID PRIMARY KEY (BON_ID);

/******************************************************************************/
/****                               Indices                                ****/
/******************************************************************************/

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_UNQ_BON_POSID_NO ON BONS (BON_POSID, BON_NUM);


I'm not sure if it's actually deterministic. I guess that they might have the same trigger position, and in that case I believe they are executed in alphabetical order. I'll see if I can found out, might take a few days before I have time though, so maybe you can experiment with that.

@MarkRotteveel, I will try :) And one linked question - is there a way to setup order of constraint check triggers manually ?

@MarkRotteveel, a change in unique index name, so it is after PK_BONS in alphabetical order does not have effect:
DROP INDEX IDX_UNQ_BON_POSID_NO; CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PPIDX_UNQ_BON_POSID_NO ON BONS (BON_POSID, BON_NUM);

In the status vector you get violated constraint name. It is easy to check which constraint it is. Besides, your program algorithm will fail in any case: sequence of operations "insert - PK violation - update - UK violation" has the same overall effect as "insert - UK violation". Just take as a rule of thumb: there can be only one key on replicated table and redesign the database accordingly.

@user13964273, in normal flow case program algorithm does not fail on attempt to update record with the same primary key, just because it is the same - there is no second record with same unique index value. Anyway, redesign DB is possible, but this is "last chance" solution.

In your question the flow is already not normal: it can produce violation of PK. Consider two records: (1,2) and (2,1). Inserting (1,1) will fail whatever you do. That's why I say that there is no need to know order in which the constraint are checked: if both insert and update fail - you have a problem that cannot be fixed by any algorithm. If any of them success - you have no problem. Just check in  your program that update updated exactly one record (which you have to do anyway if you want it to work).

With some experimenting, it seems like the order of creation decides which is fired first, the primary key or the unique key (or more specifically, the value of its RDB$INDICES.RDB$INDEX_ID), which suggest that the unique index was created before the primary key, or at least received a lower RDB$INDEX_ID, which can also happen if another index existed on the table before the primary key, and that index was dropped before the unique index was added.
Just dropping and recreating the unique index will not be sufficient. Indexes have an id per table, and if you drop one or more, subsequent creation of new indexes will reuse those ids. You will need to drop both the unique index and the primary key, and then recreate them in the desired order.
However, some more testing shows this is not guaranteed to be deterministic across a backup and restore. On backup, indexes are stored in the backup file in their physical storage order in the RDB$INDICES metadata table, and on restore, they are restored in that order, and the first index of a table will get RDB$INDEX_ID = 1, the second 2, and so on, which means their evaluation order can change.
Dropping both indexes in one transaction, and recreating them in another single transaction will make it likely their physical storage order is the same as their logical storage order, but this is not guaranteed (e.g. the first index record might not fit on the free space of an earlier data page, but the second index might).

@MarkRoteveel, thank you for your research. Unfortunately, I have achieved the same results. Finally, to avoid uncertain results, I have removed unique constraint from index and made check for unique field value in a trigger.
